# Cannot instantiate BroswerActivity in android app for handling weblinks

Tags: java, android, android-deep-link

I am writing an android app that simply handles android app links. I am on Android 11.
Basically when the user clicks on a weblink I want to receive that link in my app so that I can perform some action on the received URL.
I've tried following this guide but it didn't help me at all: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Is there a thorough guide on how to achieve this? I am going blind here but from what I understand I basically need mainly three things:

- Declaring in the manifest file an Activity with the intent filters for the the weblinks I want to open with my app.
- Creating of course a layout for my activity with a WebView.
- Creating the Activity, setting up the web view there and getting the URL there to perform the desired action.

For the simplicity of the task, let's just say I want to print the URL to console for now.
This is what I've added in the Manifest:

```
<activity android:label="test" android:name="com.developer.app.main.BrowserActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
               <data android:scheme="http" android:host="api.myserver.com" android:pathPrefix="/discord/"/>
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
               <data android:scheme="https" android:host="maps.google.com" android:pathPrefix="/maps"/>
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
               <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

The layout of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/layout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout android:id="@+id/swipeContainer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/txtLoading" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="loading" android:textAlignment="center"/>
            <com.developer.app.main.WebView android:id="@+id/webView" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

BrowserActivity:

```
public abstract class BrowserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = BrowserActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    TextView txtLoading;
    WebView webView;

    public BrowserActivity getActivity() {
        return this;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
        //ButterKnife.bind((Activity) this);

        this.swipeContainer = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        this.txtLoading = findViewById(R.id.txtLoading);
        this.webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
     
        this.txtLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setupActionBar();
        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }
    
    
    private void setupWebView(String str)
    {
       this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            this.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            this.txtLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.webView.loadUrl(str);
    }

    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ("android.intent.action.VIEW".equals(action)) {
            setupWebView(intent.getDataString());
        } else if (!"android.intent.action.SEND".equals(action)) {
            String str = TAG;
            Log.w(str, "Received unknown action: " + action);
        } else if (intent.getClipData() == null || intent.getClipData().getItemCount() <= 0) {
            finish();
        } else {
            handleData(intent.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString());
        }
    }

    private void handleData(String str)
    {
       System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

However when I click on link, (the disambiguation dialog does not appear anymore since I've set my app as default handler), the app open and crash immediately.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit with the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process: com.developer.app, PID: 11726
                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.developer.app/com.developer.app.main.BrowserActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.developer.app.main.BrowserActivity> cannot be instantiated
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4027)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:247)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8676)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
                Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.developer.app.main.BrowserActivity> cannot be instantiated
                    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
                    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3730)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4027) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:247) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8676) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: "the app open and crash immediately" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```java
public abstract class BrowserActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

with:

```java
public class BrowserActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

You are trying to actually use this class, which means it cannot be `abstract`.